# Linux software Raid LVM restore volume group

Tags: linux, lvm, restore, raid1

first of all: excuse my bad english :)

We use a Archlinux server with 3 HDD in software raid 1 mode. There should be two lvm extended partition from which i think they should be work in volume groups.
(I did not set up this system.)

Through a update the system crashed and i cant boot it.

I took a debian live persistent usb drive and get the raid and one of the volume group partition working.

The problem is that the other partition of the volume is not been loaded.
Trying

```
dd if=/dev/md1 bs=512 count=255 skip=1 of=/tmp/md1.txt
```

gives only crypted chars. Is there a way to restore the volume group?

If more information needed, i'll post them.

advanced thanks:)

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd expect from trying to read your drive like a text file?  What does `pvscan` report?  What about `lvscan`?

Comment: `pvscan  
  PV /dev/md1   VG array   lvm2 [462.62 GiB / 640.00 MiB free]  
  Total: 1 [462.62 GiB] / in use: 1 [462.62 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]  
`
    

`lvscan   
  inactive          '/dev/array/data' [462.00 GiB] inherit  
`
  
I tried to read with dd to get the volume group settings of lvm.